# Preventing SQL Injection when PDO does not prepared statement binding

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Within our multi-tenancy product, we're now looking at creating a custom role that can read data to allow third-party reporting products to access the database.

The role creation and initial permissions are done via a command for current tenants. When a new tenant is created, this process is also executed. This means there is very little user input since we generate random credentials and email them before they're then stored encrypted against the tenant.

This same role is then used in the tenant bootstrapper to connect to the database for the software.

The issue comes when the end user wants to change their database role password. Since the software utilizes the new role for its connection, we must provide a way to do this from within the back office.

PDO does not seem to support the following prepared statement query with bindings:

```php
ALTER ROLE "?" WITH PASSWORD '?'
```

Since this query must be run by the admin, preventing SQL injection is paramount. How can I achieve this security? Would creating a stored procedure and passing the parameters with binding parameters be the right way?

Comment: @Olivier not quite. They are using PDO, not pg_

Comment: Thanks for the really fast response all, its very much appreciated! I presume a stored procedure is the way to go forwards for this based on the linked answer and I will try this now. I had a feeling but I wasn’t sure if there was a better approach or not, thanks again!

Comment: Of course there is a better approach. using a stored procedure for that is a hell of a solution